# How to add an onClick function on an anchor tag wrapped in a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an anchor tag wrapped in a string.

```
export const linkify = (inputText) => {
    let replacePattern = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    if (replacePattern.test(inputText)){
        inputText=inputText.replace(replacePattern, function(url) {
            return `<a href="${url}" onClick=${() => onLinkClick()}>${url}</a>`;
        })
    }
    return inputText;
}

const onLinkClick = () => {
    // do something
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

I want to add an onClick on the anchor tag which I did but it is not working

Comment: you can't bind a onclick function to element in string , you should add a specific class or id and after it rendered in react you can get  that element again and bind your function to that element

Answer (score 0):

create element and edit it's attribute.

```js
const onLinkClick = () => {
  // do something
  console.log("clicked");
};

export const linkify = (inputText) => {
  let replacePattern =
    /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&#\/%=~_|])/gim;
  if (replacePattern.test(inputText)) {
    inputText = inputText.replace(replacePattern, function (url) {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      a.innerText = url;
      a.addEventListener("click", onLinkClick);

      return a;
    });
  }
  return inputText;
};
```